# plsql procedure that will delete rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a table `USERS` with columns `username,fname, lname, age`.

I need to create a procedure that will delete username from parameter, if the age if less than 18.

I wrote some code, but it doesn't work:

```
create procedure delete_user(username in varchar2)
as    
begin
    if exists (delete from username  where age < 18);

    dmbs_output.put_line(username);
end;
exec detele_user('mrgreen');
```

Comment: `if exists (delete ...)` is not valid SQL. You're looking for `delete from...where username =`. Try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how.

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table users
  2    (username varchar2(10),
  3     age      number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into users
  2    select 'LF'  , 10 from dual union all
  3    select 'Marc', 20 from dual;

2 rows created.
```

A procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure delete_user (p_username in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    delete from users u
  5      where u.username = p_username
  6        and u.age < 18;
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line('User ' || p_username ||
  9      case when sql%rowcount = 0 then ' NOT ' end ||
 10      ' deleted');
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

A few remarks:

- don't name parameters as table columns; Oracle won't know which is which. Use a prefix, such as `p_`
- use table aliases, always
- see example of using `sql%rowcount` which helps you know number of rows affected

Finally, testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec delete_user('LF');
User LF deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec delete_user('Marc');
User Marc NOT  deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Not related to your problem, but - it usually helps if you post code that actually compiles.

- `dmbs_` is invalid
- if you named the procedure `delete_user`, then don't call `detele_user`

Comment: i works good, but I found another problem, the username can be foreign key from another table, must to figure out how to delete it and from child table

Comment: If foreign key constraint was created with the `on delete cascade` option, Oracle would do it for you. Otherwise, manually delete row(s) from the child table, and then from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Then you basically have 3 options. 
  1. Add a column to users table indicating that "user has been deleted". Set this but do NOT actually delete the user. 
  2. Modify the FK on the child table(s) TO "ON DELETE CASCADE". (If the DBA will permit that - many/most won't).
  3. Modify procedure to delete child rows: Below is one possibility.

```
create or replace procedure delete_user (p_username in varchar2)
is
begin
   delete from child_table c
    where c.username = p_username
      and exists (select null 
                    from users u 
                   where u.username = p_username
                     and u.age < 18
                  );

   delete  from users u
    where u.username = p_username
      and u.age < 18; 

  dbms_output.put_line('User ' || p_username ||
                       case when sql%rowcount = 0 then ' NOT ' end ||
                       ' deleted');
end  delete_user ;
```

Comment: Works better than my thoughts ( with on delete cascade), thx for help